# Can I call a script/object that is in the current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to call an object in my current tab with my extension. I've already tried to call the object via

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:'console.log(OBJECT)'});
```

But that does not work. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0doW.png). It is the same command, but when i call it with the chrome.tabs.executeScript it seems to not be able to call the Object. It seems like I am not able to call javascript that's loaded on my active tab.

Is there any solution regarding this?

Comment: Actually, you can't, you can only access the script your extension added on the page/tab. Chrome runs both the website and extension scripts in an isolated environment.

Comment: Oh. Alright! Thanks for this information.

Comment: You can. [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)